# Most efficient Grid module/method with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, matrix, grid, selection

I have a web app that is built aimed primarily at iPads on full screen mode. I've got to implement a select-able grid/matrix that has two levels of selections - one main item selection and one sub item selection. It looks something like this from our design:

First picture has main item selection, and

### [image: Grid Pic 1]

### [image: Grid Pic 2]

The application is built on AngularJS, and Bootstrap3. Right now we have implemented a working version of the grid using a custom jQuery plugin we authored and now are wondering why we ever did it. The code is buggy and constantly throws up new bugs. We are looking for an alternative form of implementation, hopefully a pure AngularJS one.

The criteria we're looking for are:
 1. Responsiveness across devices - iPad/desktop
 2. Stable DOM structure compatible with filtering (search bar at the top needs to work - not shown in figures).
 3. Quick rendering from dynamically changing AJAX data.
 4. Touch friendly

What are the best methods/ng-modules to implement something like this? We are on the verge of deciding to write a custom module, but don't wanna reinvent the wheel!

We did see ng-grid, but it still seems to be in Beta. We need a stable module.
SmartTable seems to be the most decent option as of now.

TIA!

Comment: I think twitwer-bootstrap would be a good idea if you want to build a responsive layout

Comment: We are already using Bootstrap 3. I've updated the question with this.

Answer (score 3):

Have you Tried [Angular Material Gridlist](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.gridList) I think it must something more clean. I frequently use it rather than bootstrap. Hope it helps

Comment: Angular Material Design is really cool, thanks for the intro. But we don't want to replace Bootstrap as yet, as it would be too much of an overhaul. Looking for more of a solution that falls within the Angular-Bootstrap-JS-jQuery region.

Comment: The "overhaul" is oing to pay off BIG times. I was up and running with angular-material within a few days. See a functional template built in 15 minutes at ng-conf 2015 : https://youtu.be/Qi31oO5u33U?list=PLOETEcp3DkCoNnlhE-7fovYvqwVPrRiY7

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Angular Grid](http://www.angulargrid.com). I know it works on iPad, the scrolling uses touch gestures. It performs very well in comparison to other AngularJS grids. I've used it with large grids on iPads and Androids.

Answer (score 0):

Go for **[Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/)** in conjuction with **[angular-material](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.gridList)**.

Both have you covered in terms of UI elements and grid needs, and are very reliable. Both are very active frameworks.

They both reached v1 very recently.

You should seriously consider the time you're going to gain, even if at first you have to drop Bootstrap. I was anxious as well to drop ui-bootstrap, but really, you won't regret it (and you'll be wondering why you didn't do it before).

Docs are impeccable, Codepens and Plunkrs are all over the place, Blog posts abound...

Learning curve is... well... [judge for yourself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qi31oO5u33U&list=PLOETEcp3DkCoNnlhE-7fovYvqwVPrRiY7&index=28).